# Quarkus PanacheEntity not saved during tests

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm experimenting with Quarkus and Quarkus testing with RestEasy and I'm running into an issue while setting up dummy data before each of the tests.

I'm trying to insert a User using the Active Record pattern before calling the endpoint. Right after calling user.persistAndFlush() (or simply just calling .persist()) when the asking the User entity for the count of the users, it correctly gives back that there is one record in the database. However, when calling the endpoint through RestEasy, it throws back to me that the user is not found with that given identifier and indeed, when logging out the number of users in that certain method call in the service, there are 0 users according to Quarkus.
It looks to me as if the method with the @Test annotation and the service itself were running in a different context? It's a bit strange and I'm sure missing something obvious.

Here's what my test class looks like:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(PostgreSQLDatabaseResource.class)
public class AuthenticationResourceTest {

  @TestHTTPEndpoint(AuthenticationResource.class)
  @TestHTTPResource
  URL url;

  @BeforeEach
  @Transactional
  public void setUp() {
    User.deleteAll();
  }


  @Test
  public void testWithNonExistingEmail() {
    AuthenticationChallenge invalidAuthRequest = AuthenticationChallenge.builder()
        .email("admin@admin.com")
        .password("something")
        .build();

    given()
        .when()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body(invalidAuthRequest)
        .post(url)
        .then()
        .statusCode(401);
  }

  @Test
  @Transactional
  public void testWithValidAuthenticationChallenge() {
    User user = User.builder()
        .name("admin")
        .role(Roles.ADMIN)
        .status(Status.ACTIVE)
        .password(BCrypt.withDefaults().hashToString(10, "admin".toCharArray()))
        .email("admin@admin.com")
        .build();

    user.persistAndFlush();

    given()
        .when()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body(AuthenticationChallenge.builder().email("admin@admin.com").password("admin").build())
        .post(url)
        .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .log()
        .all();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your user won't be saved to the database until the end of the test method as it's transactional and the transaction is committed at the end.

With your REST call, you query your database outside of the transaction so you won't have the data.

If you want to initialize some data visible to your REST call, you need to create the data in the `@BeforeEach` method.